# App is not at full screen after lock - unlock

Tags: android, fullscreen

I noticed that when I open my app and wait enough for my phone locks itself and when i unlock it the current content view in not in full screen mode. It does not show the top bar but instead it's all black line... If i go to another activity and go back it fixes again. 
Things I tried:
 1. Inserting

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

into onCreate, onResume, onRestart methods.

1. Inserting

   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

into androidmanifest.xml

ANY OTHER SUGGESTIONS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem when I was running my application on emulator, its may be due to any bug in emulator itself,
 try running your application on real device, hopefully there you will not get that problem